# FCM Message received on Device but not emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app targeting Android API 24 and greater. It receives a data message.

When I connect my device (Moto G4 plus) running Android 7 - it receives the FCM message which is sent via the FCM API by a separate server app. I can process the data in the FCM message on the code running on the device.

However the emulators in Android Studio (API 24, 25) DO NOT receive the message at all. The emulators do show being synced with Firebase in logcat.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

### App build. gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
check.dependsOn 'assembleDebugAndroidTest'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "****"
        minSdkVersion 24

        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        //multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //For FCM
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.1'

    //For Networking
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

    //For InstanceID
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.2'


    // Testing dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: are you using Emulator with Google Apis?

Comment: Yes Itzik, I just updated the question with my build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

I un-installed and re-installed Android Studio. And the emulators can now receive the FCM Message.

I can't find a reason why this solves it but it does.

Comment: I have the same problem. I hope I don't have to do this.